# How can I show two dates in one field if one of the dates is blank?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, calculated-column

The business wants two dates to show up in one field in a SharePoint 2013 List.

I have created a calculated column which combines the two dates but I run into issues if one of the dates isn't filled out. I can get a return of "NA" if one or both of the date fields is completed but I can't get it to display if only one of the dates is completed.

Here is what I have so far.

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Audit Date 2]),"NA",IF(ISBLANK([Audit Date 1]),"NA",TEXT([Audit Date 1],"mm/dd/yy")&" & "&TEXT([Audit Date 2],"mm/dd/yy")))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Flip it around a bit - this is pseudocode obviously. If you find a blank don't do a NA immediately, do the test on the next field.If one of the date fields is more important than the other, you can test that field first.

```
If(isblank(field1),X,TextField1)
```

Where X would be your test for blank field 2

```
If(isblank(field2),"NA",TextField2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed something in the desired results description: "I can get a return of "NA" if one or both of the date fields is completed but I can't get it to display if only one of the dates is completed."

You formula creates this:

[image]

Is this what you wanted?

[image]

If so, try this formula:

```
=IF(
  and(NOT(ISBLANK([Audit Date 1])),ISBLANK([Audit Date 2])),TEXT([Audit Date 1],"mm/dd/yy"),
 IF(
  and(NOT(ISBLANK([Audit Date 2])),ISBLANK([Audit Date 1])),TEXT([Audit Date 2],"mm/dd/yy"),
 IF(
  and(NOT(ISBLANK([Audit Date 1])),NOT(ISBLANK([Audit Date 2]))),
  TEXT([Audit Date 1],"mm/dd/yy")&" & "&TEXT([Audit Date 2],"mm/dd/yy"),"NA")))
```